# Visual effects of sliding without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm quite impressed with the slider that is used with one site - lumosity. [http://www.lumosity.com/app/v5/personalization/attention] and I'm keen to replicate the slider that slides in part of the questions - however is there an elegant way to do this without recourse to jQuery? Ideally I'd like to not use JQuery and employ a much simpler way of doing things - can anyone recommend a workaround?

I'm using Django for the serving, so I'm trying to keep my pages as simple as possible. I know I could use JQuery, but is there another way to do it?

I.e.

1. Native within Django?
2. Not using jQuery?
3. 3rd party Django add-ons that would work with Google apps.

The site is here:

http://www.lumosity.com/app/v5/personalization/attention

and the effect occurs when you click "Next"

Answer (score 1):

You can do [animation purely with CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), but you would still have to trigger the animation you want client-side, unless you're doing something on page load, or another event that can be triggered automatically.

Django, being Python code running on the server-side, doesn't have a way to interact with client-side code, unless you're making a request, be it a GET, POST, PUT, etc, via an Ajax call.

Nothing says you have to leverage jQuery. You could do all the same functionality using vanilla JavaScript. However, jQuery and its ecosystem of plugins, can give you a huge productivity boost, and when loaded from a CDN, is going to add a negligible amount of weight to your view/site.